# Find the equivalent linear program

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

This is a classic question, its for a homework assignment, I have the solution but I've been breaking my head to understand how to approach the problem.

> Minimize $||A\vec x - \vec b||_1$ subject to $||x||_\infty \leq1$

and the solution given is

Minimize $\textbf{1}^T$ subject to $-y \leq A\vec x - \vec b \leq y$ and $\textbf{-1} \leq x \leq \textbf{1}$

If anyone could shed some light on how to approach this problem...

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

The constraint $\|x\|_\infty \le 1$ means max of the coordinates of $x$ cannot be more than 1 in absolute value. How do you express this in terms of a regular inequality?

Also, think about what $\|Ax-b\|_1$ looks like if we have $y = Ax-b$?